# EJB3 deployment descriptor. How to define two EJBs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

From tutorials I learn that for providing environment variables (`env-entry`) for EJB 3.0 we simply can use this:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>PersoManager</ejb-name>
        <env-entry>
            <env-entry-name>propertyName</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>count</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

But how must looks `ejb-jar.xml` if I need to provide same environment variables for two or more EJBs?

- Do I need to define exactly one `<session>` section for *every* EJB?
- If above is true, do I need to define in each `<session>` same `<env-entry>` tags, or I can define them globally?
- if I will have 2 EJBs, how EJB container will differentiate them? I think in case of two or more EJBs defined in `ejb-jar.xml` I also need to provide `<ejb-class>` tags inside each `<section>` section?

Comment: Well I do that defining variables in application servers context and load them at run-time through InitialContext lookup. Probably better way exists but...

Comment: getting your hands dirty will answer all your questions.